# Get all products of a category by its ID and the ID of a website in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to obtain a list of products inside a category searching by the category ID and the website ID.

Right now I have all the products of the category correctly, but the website filter isn't working, I selected a product to be in for example website Peru, but not Venezuela, but it doesn't respect that and it is always returning the product.

First I am obtaining the website id based on its code, which gives me the right value.
I am using setStoreId then.

This is the part of code:

```
$currentCountry = Mage::getModel('core/store')->loadConfig('ve')->getId();
$productData = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId())
                                                 ->getProductCollection()
                                                 ->setStoreId($currentCountry)
                                                 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                                 ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                                                 ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
```

In the product page, in the Websites submenu, I have checked Peru, but not Venezuela.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add:

```
$productData->addStoreFilter($currentCountry);
```